# Expo Notification not working after deployed to play store. Working fine on local development

Tags: android, react-native, expo

I have added expo notification in my react native application. It is working fine while running the application locally. But after creates a build by running `expo build:android -t app-bundle` command and deploy .aab file to the play store notifications are not working.

**I'm using the spring-boot application to send expo push notifications.**

```
const getNotificationPermission = async () => {
 const pushNotificationToken = await getStorageData(storage.NOTIFICATION_TOKEN);
 if (!pushNotificationToken) {
  Permissions.getAsync(Permissions.NOTIFICATIONS).then((object) => {
    if (!object.granted) {
      return Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.NOTIFICATIONS);
    }
    return object;
  }).then((object) => {
    if (!object.granted) {
      // throw new Error('Permission Not Granted!');
    }
  }).then(() => {
    return Notifications.getExpoPushTokenAsync();
  }).then((response) => {
    setStorageData(storage.NOTIFICATION_TOKEN, response.data);
  }).catch((err) => {
    return null;
  });
}
```

Comment: I'm using the exact same setup and they're also not working for me. They do work when I build an APK and install it directly on the device. But the AAB builds in the internal test environment do not receive any notifications =(.